# OleDb Command for CSV with Date in FileName causes Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

One of my customers has found a problem and I am quietly confident it is a bug, but I can't find any official documentation. The error is:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Trades 23.11.177.csv'

Here is the code to reproduce it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace DatesInCSVFileName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                LoadCSV(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Trades 2.csv"));
                LoadCSV(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Trades 23.11.1992.csv")); //Using this name with a date in the CSV fails on the line: adapter.Fill
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        public static DataTable LoadCSV(FileInfo theFile)
        {
            string sqlString = "Select * FROM [" + theFile.Name + "];";
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
                + theFile.DirectoryName + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";
            DataTable theCSV = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(theCSV); //This line throws the exception
                    }
                }
            }
            return theCSV;
        }
    }
}
```

I can workaround it by trying to detect dates (however numbers that aren't dates like this 23.11.177 also fail), so it's a bit of a pain.

Does anyone know if this is publicly documented somewhere? Or is there a connection string property I can use to solve it?

Comment: It apparently doesnt like dots in the name. `ABC.XYZ` and `5.17` and `5.XYZ` in names all fail with the same message.

Comment: I think the error is due to the data in the file and not the name.  Try swapping the two file names and see if you get same error.  The jet engine has issue with first column of data. It treats the first column as a primary key and occasionally will give errors.  If you add a new first column with integers sometimes these error will go away.

Comment: @jdweng I can rule that out - its not the data. In my repro I use the same file contents with 2 names.

Comment: Just close as a dupe of that one...